# How to create an array of structs containing aggregated data in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with event data from Firebase in Google BigQuery with the following columns:

```
event_date, event_timestamp, event_name, (etc..).
```

To count the number of events by event_name I use the following query:

```
SELECT event_name, count(event_name) as event_count
FROM `analytics.events_20200510`
GROUP BY event_name;
```

which results in:

[image: Query result]

I want to convert this result to an array of structs, formatted as JSON. Example:

```
{
    "events": [
        {"first_open": 69},
        {"screen_view": 510},
        {"user_engagement": 354},
        {"...": ..}
    ]
}
```

I started with

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(
STRUCT(
  ??? as events
), true)
```

but I'm stuck and don't know what should go on the *???* to make it work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

The answer below:

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(
STRUCT(
  (SELECT ARRAY (SELECT AS STRUCT event_name, count(*) AS count FROM `analytics.events_20200510` GROUP BY event_name)) AS events
), true);
```

results in

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "event_name": "session_start",
      "count": 69
    },
    {
      "event_name": "screen_view",
      "count": 510
    },
    (...)
  ]
}
```

which is almost correct, but I would like the event names to be the 'key' and the count to be the 'value' in the struct (as in my JSON example). Would this be possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I also can't tell what your problem is -- calculating the values (which are not defined) or structuring as JSON.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT '{"events": [' || STRING_AGG(events) || ']}' AS json
FROM (
  SELECT FORMAT('{"%s": %i}', event_name, COUNT(event_name)) AS events
  FROM `analytics.events_20200510`
  GROUP BY event_name
)
```

if you would run it against same data as in your question - result will be

```
Row json     
1   {"events": [{"session_start": 69},{"screen_view": 510},{"user_engahement": 354}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
with data as (
  select 'event_type1' as event_type
  union all
  select 'event_type2' as event_type
  union all
  select 'event_type3' as event_type
  union all
  select 'event_type1' as event_type
  union all
  select 'event_type2' as event_type
  union all
  select 'event_type1' as event_type
) 
select TO_JSON_STRING(t) from (
SELECT  array (
select as struct count(*) as event_count, event_type from data group by event_type
) as events
) t;
```

Output

```
{"events":[{"event_count":3,"event_type":"event_type1"},{"event_count":2,"event_type":"event_type2"},{"event_count":1,"event_type":"event_type3"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The formatting however is different from my JSON example. Isn't it possible that in the struct the event_name acts as a key, and the event count as a value?